# Cannot set input value with JS if it has 'autocomplete=off' attribute

Tags: javascript, html

**EDIT**: I have added more code and edited description to help to better illustrate the problem.

I have an input element with an 'autocomplete=off' attribute. I want to refresh the page and set that input text value to what was in it before (don't want the user to lose input data), so I store the value in the 'sessionStorage' and try to set that element with the stored value after the refresh; After form submission my input element gets blank. If I change my HTML page removing the autocomplete, it works fine (the element gets the value stored in the sessionStorage) but I don't want the autocomplete function for that element. There's a way to implement this?

JS:

```
function submitForm(e, op, id=NaN){
    //e is used to build var notification//
    //gonna skip details for the sake of simplicity//
    var notification = 'somejson'
    var formData = JSON.stringify(notification);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (op == 'add'){
        sessionStorage.setItem("pv", $('#pv').val());
        var pv = sessionStorage.getItem("pv");
        sessionStorage.setItem('reload', 'true')
        xhr.open("POST", "/sms_service/notifications/add", true);
        xhr.send(formData); 
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status == 200){
                window.location.href = "/sms_service/notifications"; 
                }
            else {
                window.location.reload();
                document.getElementById("pv").value = pv;
                console.log('pv', pv);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault()" action="" method="POST" id="addForm" novalidate>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="col-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pv" autocomplete="off" show="on">
        </div>
        <span>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-user" type="submit" value='add' 
                onClick="submitForm(this, 'add')" >Submit</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are resetting the value of 'pv' cause you are using `sessionStorage.setItem("pv", $('#pv').val());`, log your 'pv' value, and check pv is empty or not

Comment: autocomplete has nothing to do with this

Comment: After reload(), pv value is the same of the input. Field is blank tho.

Comment: @mousetail well, removing the attribute from the element give me the correct result when running the script, but with the autocompletion on. This last part is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

your code may have set the input value, then reset when reloading

the solution is
call document.getElementById("pv").value = pv;
at the top of the code

```js
var pv = sessionStorage.getItem("pv");
document.getElementById("pv").value = pv;
sessionStorage.setItem("pv", $('#pv').val());
    sessionStorage.setItem('reload', 'true')
    xhr.open("POST", "/sms_service/notifications/add", true);
    xhr.send(formData); 
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status == 200){
            window.location.href = "/sms_service/notifications"; 
            }
        else {
            window.location.reload();
            }
        }
```

the previous possibility worked because the autocomplete function did function to fill in frequently used inputs

Comment: I set the input value only if xhr.status is other than 200, that way you suggested don't work in this case.

Comment: why don't you delete reload

Comment: I need to reload the page to flash errors in this page.